# Problema al obtener chars pasados como parámetros al main y con la llamada al sistema execv

Tags: c, linux

tengo que hacer un ejercicio que acepte como argumentos el nombre de un programa y parámetros en el caso de que los tenga.

He programado esto:

```
#include<sys/types.h>   
#include<sys/wait.h>    
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char programa[10] = {}; 
    char *parametros[10];
    char* bg = "bg";
    char *guion = "-";
    char *ruta = "/usr/bin/";
    char buff[10] = {}; 
    int i;
    int contador = 0;


    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\nSintaxis de ejecucion: ejercicio7 [programa] [parámetros] [bg]+\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    sprintf(programa,"%s%s",ruta,argv[1]);
    parametros[contador] = argv[1];
    contador++;
  
    
    if(argc > 2)
    {
        for(i = 2; i < argc ; i++)
        {
           sprintf(buff,"%s%s",guion,argv[i]);
           parametros[contador] = buff;
           contador++;
        }

        parametros[contador] = 0;
    }

    printf(" %s ",programa);
    printf("\nMostrando array de parametros");
    for(i = 0; i < contador; i++)
        printf(" %s ",parametros[i]);
    

    if((execv(programa,parametros)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("\nError en el execv");
        printf("\nError %d en exec",errno); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Estoy realizando las pruebas con el programa lscpu.

Sin parámetros el programa funciona correctamente, lo llamo con ./programa lscpu

El problema viene cuando introduzco parámetros, si llamo al programa así ./programa lscpu a
, obtengo el siguiente error.

[image: 1er error]

Arriba, se ve como aparece esto /usr/bin/l-a en el lugar donde debería aparecer esto /usr/bin/lscpu .

Por otro lado si introduzco varios parámetros, por ejemplo ./ejercicio lscpu a b c debería obtener en el printf final : lscpu -a -b -c, sin embargo obtengo lscpu -c -c -c.

[image: 2º error]

Supongo que el error está en la forma que tengo de tratar el array parámetros, pero no consigo solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parametros` es un array de 10 apuntadores. Cuando asignas `parametros[contador] = buff;`, lo que estás haciendo es hacer que `parametros[contador]` apunte al inicio del string `buff` que ha sido declarado como un array de caracteres. Esto significa que todos los elementos en el array de `parametros` (excepto el primero que apunta a `argv[1]`) apuntan al mismo lugar de memoria.

Para solucionarlo, necesitas tener 10 arrays de memoria o, mejor aún, un array de `n` elementos, de `m` caracteres cada uno. En este ejemplo muestro lo más cercano a lo que estabas haciendo:

```c
    if(argc > 2)
    {
        for(i = 2; i < argc ; i++)
        {
           // 2: 1 por el `\0` y otro por el guión.
           // Si quieres que guión pueda variar fácilmente de tamaño,
           //    añade aquí un strlen(guion)
           parametros[contador] = (char*) malloc( (strlen(argv[i]) + 2) * sizeof(char));
           sprintf(parametros[contador],"%s%s",guion,argv[i]);
           contador++;
        }

        parametros[contador] = 0;
    }
```